# How to clear search contents after refreshing the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold

I am using rails 3.2 and active scaffold 3.2.3,i wanted to clear the search contents after refreshing the page(empty search fields).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply

```
   define javascript tag in your page and write this code   

   <script type="text/javascript>">

   $(document).ready(function () {

      $("your_text_field_id").val("");

    });

    </script>
```

This will surely works...